# Fixing missing boundaries in an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Say I have an integer-valued matrix such as the one displayed:

[image: color-coded image]

In the image above, the dark boundaries are represented by the number **0** and are **one pixel** wide (please ignore scaling artifacts).

Is there an efficient way of adding the missing the dark boundaries in MATLAB? (the white circles show examples of locations where boundaries are missing).

I would like to guarantee that each colored region is fully enclosed by a dark boundary under **4-wise** pixel connectivity.

Note that a solution will necessarily flip non-zero values to zero.

The matrix in question is of type **uint32** (displayed in color above).

**EDIT:** The original image is here:

[image]

Comment: More efficient than O(n) where n is the number of pixels in the image?

Comment: the keyword you are looking for is **morphological operations**: dilation/erosion, etc.. MATLAB + IPT has a bunch of functions for that.

Comment: O(n) would probably be good! although I would like to avoid looping, if possible.

Comment: Thanks @Amro. I think there is a way of doing this with subsequent calls to `diff` and maybe some morphology, but didn't come up with anything that worked.

Comment: @AmV: can you post an image without the white circles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can get fairly decent results with some simple logic involving shifted versions of your image (made using [CIRCSHIFT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/circshift.html)). Assuming a value of 0 represents the color black, this should work:

```
rawImage = ...;                            %# Your starting image
shiftedImage = circshift(rawImage,1);      %# Shift image down one row
index = (rawImage ~= shiftedImage) & ...   %# A logical matrix with ones where
        rawImage & shiftedImage;           %#   up-down neighbors differ and
                                           %#   neither is black
rawImage(index) = 0;                       %# Set those pixels to black
shiftedImage = circshift(rawImage,[0 1]);  %# Shift image right one column
index = (rawImage ~= shiftedImage) & ...   %# A logical matrix with ones where
        rawImage & shiftedImage;           %#   left-right neighbors differ and
                                           %#   neither is black
rawImage(index) = 0;                       %# Set those pixels to black
```

Comment: This works! Seriously, that was impressive. Fast, efficient and well-commented. I was trying to solve this problem using `diff` and LUTs, but I like your solution better (I think LUTs are slower).